# Project dependency in Ant

Tags: ant

I have 2 projects

1. A test project say A which has some test cases.
2. A application project which is to be tested, say B

Now, my test project A uses some of the resource files present in the application project B.
I can build my project using eclipse by adding the B reference in java build path->Projects tab for the A project.

Now i want to build the same project A using command line through Ant. What should I specify in the build.xml so that it refer the B project resource files.

When I build the A project without any reference added in build.xml it gives me error "symbols not found" in the java files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Ant doesn't manage the dependencies for you out of the box.

so you need to take the artifacts built by Project B and use them in the classpath for Project A.

For instance, assuming your Projects a residing a sibling folders 
Root dir:

```
A / build.xml
  /target/
  / ...
B / build.xml
  /target
  / ...
```

In A build.xml., add:

```
     <pathelement location="${basedir}/../B/target/B.jar" />
```

And it should be able to find your built jar/artifact.

[Edit] OK, I edited this answer because I had my A & B's all mixed up.